# Define a Class in Python that has a property of it's own Class (recursion)

Tags: python, class, recursion

I'm trying to model a file-system structure in Python. My file-system has two types of objects:

- `File`: **always** has a `containing_folder`
- `Folder`: **optionally** has a `containing_folder`

I have the following code now:

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, name: str, containing_folder: Folder):
        self.name = name
        self.containing_folder = containing_folder

class File:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size: int, containing_folder: Folder):
        self.name = name
        self.containing_folder = containing_folder
```

I get the following error on `def __init__()` when defining `Class Folder`:

`NameError: name 'Folder' is not defined`

I understand why I get the error, but I don't know how to fix it. I can omit the type from the parameter `containing_folder` but I'd rather be **explicit** about it.

**Questions**

- Any ideas on how to define this recursive structure?
- Any ideas on how to make the `containing_folder` optional for the `Class Folder`?

Answer (score 2):

When using type hint of a class inside itself, you need to surround it with quotes (or double quotes).

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, name: str, containing_folder: 'Folder'):
        self.name = name
        self.containing_folder = containing_folder
```

Comment: Additionally, you might want to make `containing_folder` of type `Optional['Folder']` rather than simply `'Folder'` to account for the root case. You will indeed need to create this root `Folder` instance, which will have no parent, thus needing the `containing_folder` to have a default value of another type than `'Folder'`. `Optional` makes it so that the value can be `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You should import `annotations` from `__futures__` and it will work as expected. To make `containing_folder` optional, just add a default value like `None` and add typing information about optional value:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional


class Folder:
    def __init__(self, name: str, containing_folder: Optional[Folder] = None):
        self.name = name
        self.containing_folder = containing_folder


class File:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size: int, containing_folder: Folder):
        self.name = name
        self.containing_folder = containing_folder
```

Note: `Optional[Folder] == Folder | None` for python >= 3.10 or `Optional[Folder] == Union[Folder, None]` for all python 3 versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know about `__future__`. Works like a charm. Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) to Python docs with more information if someone else is interested.

Answer (score 0):

For (currently) future reference, the [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) should introduce the `Self` type hint in Python 3.11. According to [the PEP 673 description](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-parameter-types), it should work as follow:

```py
from typing import Self

class Shape:
    def difference(self: Self, other: Self) -> float:
        pass
```

Additionally, it will introduce more flexibility, consider the following example (taken from [the PEP 673 description](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#motivation)):

```py
from typing import Self

class Shape:
    def set_scale(self, scale: float) -> Self:
        self.scale = scale
        return self


class Circle(Shape):
    def set_radius(self, radius: float) -> Self:
        self.radius = radius
        return self
```

In this case, the type of `Circle().set_scale(0.5)` will be correctly inferred as `Circle`.
Without `Self`, a simple typing of `set_scale` would have been `def set_scale(self, scale: float) -> Self:` but `Circle().set_scale(0.5)` would have been inferred as `Shape` instead.
In the same case, a more convoluted way to handle the typing would have been to use a `TypeVar` bound to the base class, but this would be harder to understand.